# Change Date Column with different format Pandas python

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, date

**Hello World,**

New in Python, I am struggling to clean a date column but with different format.

Here is **a sample** DF

```
date
01.01.2001
1.01.2001
01.1.2001
1.1.2001
01.2001
1.2001
01012001
01.01
1.01.01
010101
1.1.01
```

All those rows gave the same information.

**However, as you can imagine, the real Df contains different dates but with same different formats**

My Question how can I convert those rows in order to retrieve the following output

```
date
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
01.01.2001
```

Thanks for anyone helping!

Comment: How would you interpret `112001` is it `1.12.2001` or `11.2.2001`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang  Thanks for the info, I'll update the question

Comment: I have an idea: `df['date'] = '01.01.2001'`

Comment: if all dates are the same, why format it instead of creating a new dataframe with that date and as many columns as the original df?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], day_first=True)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, ParserError: String does not contain a date: .

Comment: '01.01.2001', '1.01.2001', '01.1.2001', '1.1.2001', '1.01.01', '010101', '1.1.01' can be converted using `pd.to_datetime(df['column_name'], day_first=True)` as Quang Hoang suggested. But the others are not handled by `pd.to_datetime` unless you specify the `format` of each date as arg to `pd.to_datetime()`. Some cases do not have the day/month.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @Gamopo made a good point, why even parse these dates at all? In any case, we're going to need a complete explanation of how the dates should be parsed.

Comment: If all dates are the same, I think @CeliusStingher answer should work